# Hard body Solar/Rocket powered wing shaped stratospheric super sonic blimp capable of orbit?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, orbital-motion, aerodynamics, space

I got many down votes for the idea that a blimp being used for space travel especially in the launch an re-entry area but, once the blimp is high enough in the Stratosphere could it not be capable of faster speeds? If the blimp was wing shaped enough and reached an altitude where it was no longer buoyant that it could serve more as a wing as its speed increases and achieve orbital speeds as it gains altitude?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JP_Aerospace

Comment: Ask yourself what would be the point of your contraption. If I try to answer this question, I come up empty.

Comment: @Pirx to put distance between the engine and the crew capsule.  To allow for a stratospheric launch unlike the sky hook the booster rockets would separate and the main engine would  stay with the blimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I think the best space application for extremely high altitude dirigibles or heliostats is with lofting telescopes. At $30,000$ meters you have near $.1\%$ the atmosphere density at sea level. I refer to the image of the atmospheric profile from the [wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth) . There is a variation in the speed of sound that decreases at these altitudes.

The energy advantage of lofting with gas to high altitudes is not very strong. The energy saving is comparatively small and there are difficulties with dirigibles that are long standing. Trying to get them to move at high velocity means there are stresses on the body that would be difficult to engineer around.

Comment: I love the way you say yes!!!